# How to merge values ​for each key into an array

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var myArray = [
    {id: '1', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'BBB'},
    {id: '4', product: 'CCCC'}
];
```

the desired result.
Output:

var result = {id: [1,2,2,4],product:['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCCC']}

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your output is not valid JS. You can have `var result = {id: [1,2,2,4],product:['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCCC']}` for example using reduce

Comment: You might want to have a look at `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` (or `Object.entries()`) and to `Array.prototype.reduce()`. That said, your expected output `[id: [1,2,2,4],product:['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCCC']]` is not valid JavaScript; you can either get `{id: [1,2,2,4],product:['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCCC']}` or `[[1,2,2,4], ['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCCC']]`

Comment: Corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using a simple loop:

```js
const input = [
    {id: '1', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'BBB'},
    {id: '4', product: 'CCCC'}
];

const result = { id: [], product: []};

for (const value of input) {
  result.id.push(value.id);
  result.product.push(value.product);
}

console.log(result);
```

Or the other way around:

```js
const input = {
  id: [1, 2, 4, 4],
  product: ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCCC']
};

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.id.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    id: input.id[i],
    product: input.product[i]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to also do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Using a reduce

```js
var myArray = [
    {id: '1', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'AAA'},
    {id: '2', product: 'BBB'},
    {id: '4', product: 'CCCC'}
];
const obj = myArray.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  acc.id.push(cur.id);
  acc.product.push(cur.product);
  return acc;
},{id:[],product:[]});

console.log(obj)
```